# How to implement the statistical facet together with the histogram facet or the date histogram facet in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

In this documentation regarding [statistical facet in ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/statistical-facet.html),  at the bottom of the page, it seems to imply that we can implement the histogram facet but it does not teach us how.

Could anyone tell me how do you implement statistical facet along with the histogram facet and the date histogram facet with examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference to the histogram facet at the bottom of the statistical facet page seems to be just a copy and paste error. It should read "In order to implement the *statistical* facet,..."

Examples of histogram and date histogram facets can be found here:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/histogram-facet.html 
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/date-histogram-facet.html

Comment: Histrogram facet is like a statistical facet but versus time